# Remove Duplicate Values Without Distinct and Change Into NULL Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to remove duplicate rows and convert the duplicated ones into null values, but I don't know how to do it in SQL Server

Here is my snippets of my table records

| RefNo | TrxDate | TrxID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1238688846 | 2021-05-26 18:35:54.393 | '2f01b431-bca5-4d84-cd90-d5a8727a782d |
| 1238688846 | 2021-05-26 18:33:48.993 | '2f01b431-bca5-4d84-cd90-d5a8727a782d |

My expected result is change to NULL Values on row which is contain smallest date

| RefNo | TrxDate | TrxID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1238688846 | 2021-05-26 18:35:54.393 | '2f01b431-bca5-4d84-cd90-d5a8727a782d |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |

Here is my code snippets

```
SELECT 
    X.ReferenceNo,
    X.TransactionDate,
    Y.TransactionID,
FROM [TABLE] X
INNER JOIN [TABLE] Y ON X.Key1  = X.Key1 
    AND RIGHT(Y.Key2,10) = RIGHT(X.Key2,10)
    AND Y.Key3 = 'Blablabla'
    AND X.Key4 <> Y.Key4
```

Your answer will be so helpful. Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to keep null rows anyway? Why not remove them?

Comment: @DaleK I need to keep null rows because I'll insert them into temporary table

Comment: But you could have multiple nulls rows with no way to distinguish them? Oh well, I guess you know what you are doing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some `CASE` expressions with `ROW_NUMBER`. The `PARTITION BY` clause is a guess, as we have minimal expected results and no sample data (so I can't test), so you may need to amend it appropriately:

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Y.TransactionID ORDER BY X.TransactionDate DESC) WHEN 1 THEN X.ReferenceNo END AS ReferenceNo,
    CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Y.TransactionID ORDER BY X.TransactionDate DESC) WHEN 1 THEN X.TransactionDate END AS TransactionDate,
    CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Y.TransactionID ORDER BY X.TransactionDate DESC) WHEN 1 THEN Y.TransactionID END AS TransactionID
FROM [TABLE] X
INNER JOIN [TABLE] Y ON X.Key1  = X.Key1 
    AND RIGHT(Y.Key2,10) = RIGHT(X.Key2,10)
    AND Y.Key3 = 'Blablabla'
    AND X.Key4 <> Y.Key4;
```

Comment: Wow !! thank you for your answer, it meets my needs, I need this to insert into Temporary Table

Comment: Then just preceed the statement with an `INSERT` clause top your temporary table, @Arya .

Comment: @Larnu . . . For this to work reliably, you need an `order by` in the outer query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no you don't, the `ORDER BY` for `ROW_NUMBER` is determined by the `OVER` clause *not* the outer query's `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Larnu . . . The OP wants the `NULL` values returns after the rows with values.  There is no ordering in a query unless the outer query has an `order by`.

Comment: As the OP is [inserting the data into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68903985/remove-duplicate-values-without-distinct-and-change-into-null-values/68904030?noredirect=1#comment121775507_68904030), @GordonLinoff , then the `ORDER BY` would need to be at the final `SELECT` statement; as you are well aware tables are stored in heaps, so inserting the data in a specific order achieves nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a CTE and `row_number()` only once (because I dislike having to repeat expressions in a query) with `case` expressions to null out the unwanted values.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        X.ReferenceNo
        , X.TransactionDate
        , Y.TransactionID
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X.ReferenceNo ORDER BY X.TransactionDate DESC) rn
    FROM [TABLE] X
    INNER JOIN [TABLE] Y ON X.Key1  = X.Key1 
        AND RIGHT(Y.Key2,10) = RIGHT(X.Key2,10)
        AND Y.Key3 = 'Blablabla'
        AND X.Key4 <> Y.Key4
)
SELECT
  CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN NULL ELSE ReferenceNo END ReferenceNo
  , CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN NULL ELSE TransactionDate END TransactionDate
  , CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN NULL ELSE TransactionID END TransactionID
FROM CTE;
```